# How to deal with a case of Polymorphic Association

Tags: postgresql, database-design, polymorphic-associations

In our app, multiple types of users (corporate clients, standard customers, company employees, workers) are able to open tickets on Customer Support page. When a new Ticket is created, it should have an Author property. Now, there are three approaches in my mind to design a solution:

1. Having general "Users" table and many child tables for each type of users and one general "Tickets" table and "author_id" field referencing general "Users" table.

   ```
   Tickets: ticket_id (PK) | author_id (FK)
   ```
2. Having separate independent user tables for each type of users and general "Tickets" table and many child tables for each type of user tickets (corporate client tickets, standard customer tickets, company employee tickets, worker tickets), each referencing the appropriate user table with one to many relationship:

   ```
   Tickets: ticket_id (PK) | (other ticket data fields...)

   CorporateClientTickets: ticket_id (PK, FK) | corporate_client_id (FK)

   StandardCustomerTickets: ticket_id (PK, FK) | standard_customer_id (FK)

   CompanyEmployeeTickets: ticket_id (PK, FK) | company_employee_id (FK)

   WorkerTickets: ticket_id (PK, FK) | worker_id (FK)
   ```
3. Having separate independent user tables for each type of users and general "Tickets" table and multiple NULLable fields like "corporate_client_id", "standard_customer_id", "company_employee_id", "worker_id" for each type of users and filling one of them according to the type of ticket author and keeping others as NULL.

   ```
   Tickets: ticket_id (PK) | corporate_client_id (FK) | standard_customer_id (FK) | company_employee_id (FK) | worker_id (FK) | (other ticket data fields...)
   ```

I would like to know your approach and the "why" of your approach.

Edit: Currently, there are no different columns among ticket types, all should have ticket id, author id, title, and status (open or closed), that's all.

Comment: Questions about subtypes come up all the time here.  You might want to visit the [tag:subtypes] tag and look up the info or study some of the questions and their answers.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much more about how you intend to use the data and the different business rules applied for users and tickets. Without that I offer a forth option. One Users table,  one Tickets table with FK to users and a type code indicating the ticket type. This is the simplest and most flexible organization given the limited information provided. The real question would be what other columns each table contains and the intended use. In short you may need to consider **much** more than just PK, FK.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Currently, there are no different columns among ticket types, all should have ticket id, author id, title, and status (open or closed), that's all.

Comment: Then there is NO Difference, except for statistical analysis you might want to do. So just add a type column have just 2 table. Simpler is always better.

Comment: Are there any differences in the data about different kinds of users?  if so, checkout [tag:class-table-inheritance].